# Python: Updating a list of values in a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have created a dictionary called **matrix** that has a keys 0 to 3 and then the values are a list of names.  Each key has the same values (the list of names).  As I assign a node to a name I would like to update the dictionary to remove that name from only one key.As the code below shows, if I want to update key 0 by removing the value "jason", it removes "jason" from all of the other keys as well. I still need "jason" to be a value for keys 1 through 3 after it is removed only from key 0.

```
node = [0,1,2,3]
names = ["jason", "martin", "ronnie", "mike"]

def table (node, names):
     options = {} 
     for i in range(len(node)):
         options [i] = names
     return options    

matrix = table(node,names)
print "Before removing Jason: " + str(matrix)
alist = matrix[0]
alist.remove('jason')
matrix[0] = alist
print "After removing Jason: " + str(matrix)
print matrix
```

---

I have also included a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the keys in your dictionary refer to the same list. What you want is to assign a copy of that list to each key so the copies can be modified independently. Replace this code:

```
for i in range(len(node)):
     options [i] = names
```

with

```
for i in range(len(node)):
     options [i] = names[:]
```

Answer (score 1):

List are reference in python, which mean:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = a
>>> a is b
True
>>> a[0] = 4
>>> b
[4, 2, 3]
```

If you want to create a new list, you  have to do:

```
options [i] = list(names)
```

Answer (score 0):

solution: instead of assigning `names` assign `names[:]` since you were assigning each time the same reference.

`names[:]` (since `names` is a standard list) will create a copy of `names` since you're slicing everything.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is create a new array instead of modifying the array.

```
node = [0,1,2,3]
names = ["jason", "martin", "ronnie", "mike"]

def table (node, names):
    options = {} 
    for i in range(len(node)):
        options [i] = names
    return options    

matrix = table(node,names)
print "Before removing Jason: " + str(matrix)
matrix[0] = [x for x in alist where x is not 'jason']
print "After removing Jason: " + str(matrix)
print matrix
```